# AngularJS + Bootstrap - inject $compiled HTML into popover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I am trying to build dynamic content for the popover of a series of elements.

Using this directive:

```
.directive('popover', function($compile){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // define popover for this element
            $(element).popover({
                html: true,
                placement: "top",
                // grab popover content from the next element
                content: $(element).siblings(".pop-content").html()
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The popover's content contains the HTML content of the .pop-content sibling of the popover:

```
<div ng-repeat="o in os">
    <a popover href="javascript:;">
        show popover
    </a>

    <div ng-hide="true" class="pop-content">
        {{ 3+4 }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the content of the popover will remain the uncompiled, raw html and not a rendered angular template:

[image]

How can I inject the fully rendered Angular template (which will use directives such as ng-click and ng-hide) into the popover?
I tried calling `$compile( (element).siblings(".pop-content").html() )(scope)` as `content` but results in completely empty popovers.

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track with using $compile; however, you need to pass $compile the `.contents()` not the `.html()`:

```
// grab popover content from the next element
content: $compile( $(element).siblings(".pop-content").contents() )(scope)
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fScua/766/)

Comment: @doque Curious. After *fiddling* around I think this might just be a bug with Angular, particularly because HTML comments for each iteration in the directive are still produced, despite no actual HTML to go with them.  The scope is intact, the array is available, and other directives seem to play nice within it, but ng-repeat has this strange behavior even without referencing any model:    [Strange behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/exhz2kpr/2/)

Comment: If you don't need ng-repeat specifically within the popover content, but rather for the parent element, then that should still be good to go:

[ngRepeat container](http://jsfiddle.net/exhz2kpr/3/)

Comment: Yes @Christopher, it's quite odd. I was able to (somehow) get `ng-repeat` to  work ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578446/angularjs-ng-repeat-applied-multiple-times-in-compiled-directive)), but now it's being repeated multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find the answer. One needs to pass `scope`as a parameter to the function returned by `$compile`:

```
.directive('popover', function($compile){
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var tpl = $(element).find('.pop-content').html();

        $(element).popover({
            html: true,
            placement: "top",
            content: $compile(tpl)(scope)
        });

    };
});
```

Further, I changed the `.popover-content` to be a child element of `element`:

```
<div popover>
     <div class="popover-content">{{ 3+4 }}</div>
</div>
```