# AngularJS ng-repeat applied multiple times in $compiled directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've written a directive that dynamically creates a popover for an element:

```
app.directive('popover', function($compile, $timeout){
    return {    
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            $timeout(function() {

                // grab template
                var tpl = $(element).find('.popover-template')

                // grab popover parts of template
                var template = {
                    //$compile( $(element).siblings(".pop-content").contents() )(scope)
                    title: tpl.find('.template-title').contents(),
                    content: tpl.find('.template-content').contents()
                };

                // render template with angular
                var content = $compile(template.content)(scope);
                var title = $compile(template.title)(scope); 

                $(element).popover({
                    html: true,
                    placement: "right",
                    content: content,
                    title: title
                });

                scope.$digest()
            });

        }

    };
});
```

In application it looks like this:

```
<span popover>Click me</span>
<div ng-hide="true" class="popover-template">
    <div class="template-title">
        <strong>{{ x.name }} and {{ y.name }}</strong>
    </div>

    <div class="template-content">
        <div>
            <pre>f in [1,2,3]</pre>
            <div ng-repeat="f in [1,2,3]">
                item {{ f }}, index {{ $index }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The popover is created and displayed. The title works correctly as well. However, **ng-repeat** is applied multiple times in any iteration:

[image]

As you can see, the iteration that should only include 3 elements in fact includes 3*3 elements. The directive creates popovers for exactly 3 elements, so I guess that's where my mistake lies. How can I make sure that within each popover, `ng-repeat` is only called once?

Comment: Try to put the code in a compile block

Comment: @Whisher can you elaborate? I would like to keep the popover content inside the main template.

Comment: in the directive instead of putting the code into a link block try to put it in a compile block so the code is compiled once.I take a quick look at yours code so ... I could be wrong ^^ BTW an other thing I don't understand is why do you use $digest there is no needs to update the scope

Comment: @Whisher But do I have access to the directive's element in the compile function?

Answer (score 0):

## The problem

Since the popover-template element is already in the document when you bootstrapped the angular application (at page load), it has already been compiled once. The ng-repeat element is replaced with 3 new elements:

```
<!-- original -->
<div ng-repeat="f in [1,2,3]">item {{ f }}, index {{ $index }}</div>

<!-- replaced -->
<div ng-repeat="f in [1,2,3]">item 1, index 0</div>
<div ng-repeat="f in [1,2,3]">item 2, index 1</div>
<div ng-repeat="f in [1,2,3]">item 3, index 2</div>
```

When you compile it again in the link function, each of the 3 ng-repeats is triggered, making 3 identical copies, 9 total.

## The solution

Keep your popover-template in a separate file so it is not compiled on page load. You can then load it with the [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) service.

In general, just make sure you don't compile your HTML multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

Instead using the compiled html for the popover template, load the template using $http or templateCache.

The HTML:

```
<span popover>Click me</span>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="popover.html">
  <div class="popover-template">
    <div class="template-title">
      <strong>{{ x.name }} and {{ y.name }}</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="template-content">
      <div>
        <pre>f in [1,2,3] track by $index</pre>
        <div ng-repeat="f in [1,2,3]">
          item {{ f }}, index {{ $index }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

The Javascript:

```
angular.module('app',[]).directive('popover', function($compile, $timeout, $templateCache){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            $timeout(function() {
                // grab the template (this is the catch)
                // you can pass the template name as a binding if you want to be loaded dynamically

                var tpl = angular.element($templateCache.get('popover.html'));

                // grab popover parts of template
                var template = {
                    title: tpl.find('.template-title').contents(),
                    content: tpl.find('.template-content').contents()
                };

                // render template with angular
                var content = $compile(template.content)(scope);
                var title = $compile(template.title)(scope); 

                $(element).popover({
                    html: true,
                    placement: "right",
                    content: content,
                    title: title
                });

                scope.$digest()
            });

        }

    };
});
```

Also, I have made this plunker with an working example: http://embed.plnkr.co/IoIG1Y1DT8RO4tQydXnX/

Comment: This question is two years old, and you posted an answer which is a link to a plunker result that doesn't even show the code you used to come to the solution.  Even if the poster or others were still searching for an answer to this problem after two years, this doesn't help them.